# Deploying qt mysql application

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, dll, deployment

I have developed an application that uses Qt + MySQL.

```
connection = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

I've successfully compiled the mysql drivers, my application works and everything is fine. Now I'm trying to deploy my application, distribuing along with it all the DLLs needed.

So far I have included:

```
platforms/qwindows.dll
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
libEGL.dll     // not needed but included anyway
libmysql.dll   // compiled drivers
```

Now to test it I rename the `C:\Qt` folder to something else (i.e. `C:\Qthidden`). I run my application but it when launched it cannot connect to the database (I'm testing it on the same machine I made the program which have the MySQL server running).

I have also tried to put in `qsqlmysql.dll` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I'm currently using Qt 5.3 and MySQL 5.5.

Any ideas? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: `connection.lastError().text();` reports "Driver not loaded". What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place `qsqlmysql.dll` in a directory named `sqldrivers` alongside the executable.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had erroneuosly created a folder called `qsqldrivers` instead of `sqldrivers` when testing by myself. Thank you for your answer and time.