# Deploy Qt MySql Application

Tags: mysql, qt

I'm working on Win10 64bit with Qt5.10.1, VS2017, MySql 8.0(64it). Everything is fine in my computer. After I deploy my application on other computers, a error message "Driver not load" pop up.

I have checked many forums including two posts in stackoverflow, [[Qt][QMYSQL] Deployed app - Driver not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156663/qtqmysql-deployed-app-driver-not-loaded)
[Deploying qt mysql application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866083/deploying-qt-mysql-application)
But it doesn't work for me. The following are the dll files in my folder:

[image]

qsqlmysql.dll is included in the folder sqldrivers.
All of the platform, software, SDK are 64 bit. can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: Check it with Dependency Walker, probably the dll needs some external dependencies (MinGW dlls, C runtime etc.)

Comment: Use the winqtdeploy.exe tool coming along with the Qt installation to generate the binary package if you already don't. And as @folibis said, use a dependency checker.

Comment: The package was generated by windeployqt command. I tried Dependency walker and didn't find suspicious hints. The application can be run on my computer, dose it means that all correct DLLs are included in my computer?  Some people said that I need to recompile Qt SQL driver to generate a new 'qsqlmysql.dll', is it correct?  However, if the driver is not correct, I don't think the program can run on my computer.

Comment: To be clear, you're running it via Dependency Walker on a computer where it's encountering the error, correct?

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem 1 min ago, I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who answer my question. I tried many methods and almost give up. I never used MySQL before and this time I choose the newest MySql 8.0.12.  I ignore the procedure and post the solution directly:

Beside libmysql.dll and qsqlmysql.dll, other two *.dll files are also necessary (but no solution I searched refers to them): libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, they are located at MySql/bin/. For my computer, they are contained in the system path, while for other computers that do not install MySql, they lack these two. Thus, we need to copy them to the package as well.

For anyone who encounter the same problem, for example using the newest MySql 8.0, you can try this method.